# Compose an Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm not expert in curl and I need compose an Ajax call. This is requirement:

```
curl -F 'access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN' \
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/likes
```

What does -F mean?

Below my ajax call but I don't know where insert -F:

```
var url='https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/731833501888524747_38804843/likes';

                $.ajax({
                    url: url,  


                    success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR) {   

                   console.log(data);
                    },    
                    error: function(obj) {

                    console.log(obj);

                    },

                });
```

I've trie also with:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/731776229967638865_38804843/likes/?access_token=129219*****a59a4da481c65
```

but only returns me likes number.

Comment: Have you tried: 
url: url + '/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN' ?

Comment: Yes, see up, I've edited post @MatúšBartko

Comment: "*What does -F mean?*" It sets a `name=value` pair as though it were submitted from a `<form>`. It also changes the method (`type`) to `POST`. http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-F

Answer (score 0):

The `-F` lets curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has pressed the submit button. This causes curl to POST data using the Content-Type `multipart/form-data`.

Also I think if you're working on ajax calls, the [official documentation](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/) will definitely come in handy as you can make an ajax call and have data type set to `JSONP` like so:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/coffee/media/recent?access_token=fb2e77d.47a0479900504cb3ab4a1f626d174d2d&callback=callbackFunction
```

As far as getting the ajax request to work properly, I would really suggest you give it a try yourself. Here's the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). It's only a matter of setting in the right parameters and specifying the correct URL that you would want to make the request to and have the correct data type filled in, although it tries to determine that itself.

I hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: I've tried but nothing,is it correct to chain access token directly in the url?